# Текстовая форма

Tags: jquery, редактор, textarea, форма

Премного извиняюсь, но не получается выразить свою мысль достойным образом, поэтому объясню на пальцах:
Вот когда на любом форуме сообщение пишешь, так куча кнопочек, например сделать жирным, выровнять по центру, изменить цвет, размер, вставить картинку, ссылку.. Нет ли в интернете готовой конструкции для всего этого? Может в jQuery есть что-нибудь подобное? А то не хочется самому мучиться с этим.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Копайте в сторону WYSIWYG-редакторов

Comment: Премного благодарен.  
Был немного напуган страшным словом, оказалось оно расшифровывается  What You See Is What You Get).

Answer (score 1):

[Вот](http://habrahabr.ru/post/129262/) кстати неплохая подборка редакторов

Comment: Спасибо, однако уже сам наткнулся на эту страницу)